# Is there a way to ignore a char when getting user input for array?

Tags: c++, arrays

in C++ I am creating a program that asks a user for a date in the following format: MM/DD/YYYY. Since the date is an int and must be an int, I figured the most logical way to get this in one line is if I was to use an array.

So I created something like this...

```
int dateArray[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    cin >> dateArray[i];
int month = dateArray[0];
...etc
```

My question is if a user enters "1/23/1980" is there a way I can ignore the / that the user inputs?

Thank you.

Comment: [std::istream::ignore()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Comment: how would I use it within this context though?

Comment: Doesn't the example given in the linked reference help? Just use `'/'` instead of `'\n'` and only numeric inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore one character using `std::istream::ignore()`. Since you probably only want to ignore intervening characters, you'd need to know when to ignore and when not to ignore. For a date I would personally not bother but just read the three terms:

```
if (((std::cin >> month).ignore() >> year).ignore() >> day) {
    // do something with the date
}
else {
    // deal with input errors
}
```

I would actually also be inclined to check that the correct separator is received and probably just create a *manipulator* for this purpose:

```
std::istream& slash(std::istream& in) {
    if ((in >> std::ws).peek() != '/') {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    else {
        in.ignore();
    }
    return in;
}

// ....
if (std::cin >> month >> slash >> year >> slash >> day) {
    // ...
}
```

... and, obviously, I would check in all cases that the input is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using C++11 regular expression library support for this type of parsing.  For instance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>


int main()
{
  std::string string{ "12/34/5678" };
  std::regex regex{ R"((\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}))" };

  auto regexIterator = std::sregex_iterator( std::begin( string ), std::end( string ), regex );

  std::vector< std::string > mdy;
  for( auto matchItor = regexIterator; matchItor != std::sregex_iterator{}; ++matchItor )
  {
    std::smatch match{ *matchItor };
    mdy.push_back( match.str() );
  }

  const std::size_t mdySize{ mdy.size() };
  for( std::size_t matchIndex{ 0 }; matchIndex < mdySize; ++matchIndex )
  {
    if( matchIndex != mdySize && matchIndex != 0 ) std::cout << '/';
    std::cout << mdy.at( matchIndex );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not ignore it; it's part of your format, even though you do not need to keep it around indefinitely.

I would read it into a `char` and make sure that it is, in fact, a `/`.